# setdefault appends to each key

Tags: python, dictionary

I get strange results when using the setdefault method:

```
def initialize_dict(patients, default):
    d = {}
    for patient in patients:
        d.setdefault(patient, default)
    return d

keys = ["A", "B"]
values = initialize_dict(keys, [])
values["A"].append(1)
values
{'A': [1], 'B': [1]}
```

Why does it append 1 to "A" and "B"?
Thanks!

Comment: You always add the same list to the different dictionary entries.

Comment: fwiw use `dict.fromkeys(keys,[])` or `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @python_learner THose two are very different. `from_keys` will behave as the OP's code, the defaultdict approach makes more sense.

Comment: To create a (shallow) copy of a list, append `[:]` to it.

Comment: sorry, I didnt get your point, `dict.fromkeys` does exactly what the OP wants yeah, `defaultdict` does the same but without the keys inserted right? @schwobaseggl

Comment: @python_learner No, "dict.fromkeys" uses the same value object for each key. It does what the original code does but not what it should do.

Comment: ahh, thanks for pointing it out :) didnt use the REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
values = initialize_dict(keys, [])
```

What happens here:

- initialize_dict is called with two lists: one for keys and **one** for the default value

Looking into:

```
def initialize_dict(patients, default):
    d = {}
    for patient in patients:
        d.setdefault(patient, default)
    return d
```

What you do is take the default value and assign it to the keys. Note however, that there was always only one list created! In other words, the same list is assigned as the value of `d["A"]` and `d["B"]` - or maybe better, they both point to the same object in memory. As a result, modifying `d["A"]` changes the value of `d["B"]`

To avoid this, one solution would be to copy the default value

```
from copy import copy

def initialize_dict(patients, default):
    d = {}
    for patient in patients:
        d.setdefault(patient, copy(default)) # << HERE!
    return d
```

Note that by default, [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) does a shallow copy. Depending on what you are trying to do you might need to use `copy.deepcopy`

Finally, as others have said, this is a good fit/use-case for [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)